# How to pass query parameter to Sling model exporter

Tags: aem

I have to implement one API where the API should export the JSON data. For example, there is one container component and many child components. Lets suppose, container component is holding the country and child component is strong different states and its population etc.

So the responsibility of the API is to search the population based on the state name or other query parameter.
One of the option I am thinking about using Sling model exporter because I do not have to write Sling servlet and it is easy to export the child components as json but the problem is, I could not find an option to pass request parameter to Sling model.
For example http://some.com/country/jcr:content/parent-component.model.json will give the result of child components but here how can I pass request parameter to this model endpoint for a specific state?

I know its possible to create a sling servlet but is it possible to do it using Sling model exporter?

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the `SlingHttpServletRequest` in your model, and get the request parameter there from. Either in the getters or in your `@PostConstruct` method.

But there are no injectors available for the RequestParameters. This was for security reasons. So if you just use `@Inject`, then it just cannot happen that unwanted values are injected.

PS: The `@RequestAttribute` injector is for request-attributes, which are **NOT** query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I did face exactly the same issue and looks like the sling model exporter is dropping the parameters however I was able to solve this using **request.getHeader("referrer")** which gives us the complete URL including the parameters from which we can extract parameters.